# In batch open an xls and / or xlsx; record and close

Tags: batch-file

how do I in batch open an xls and / or xlsx; record and close one at a time in a directory.
I need the file change the creation date.
Can help me?

```
@echo off
set excel_program=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\excel.exe
start %excel_program% file1.xls; file2.xls; file3.xls
```

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with graphical user interface programs.  You are limited to starting the program only.  You will need to use Vbscript or Powershell to edit the excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a windows touch port could be an alternative.

When using powershell, it could as well handle the 3 files in one go.

```
powershell -nop -c "1..3|foreach {(gi \"file$_.xls\").Creationtime=get-date}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the date and time stamps there may be no need to open the files at all; using the `Copy` command could work for you:

```bat
@For %%A In ("file1.xls","file2.xls","file3.xls") Do @Copy /B "%%~A"+Nul "%%~A.tmp" && Move /Y "%%~A.tmp" "%%~A"
```

Comment: Sounds like they wanted the creation date changed.  This will change the modified date.

Comment: I tested on an old file and it only changed the modified date.  The create date is still in 2012, last access date is in 2013 and the modified date is now 2018.

Comment: Looks like you can do it with powershell though. I know you are much better as PS then I am so if you get to an answer before me, feel free to add that to your answer.

Comment: Id use `powershell -nop -c "Get-Item '%%~A' |ForEach{$_.CreationTime=[datetime]::now}"`

Comment: @LotPings, do you need the pipe?  Couldn't it be done this way: `powershell "(Get-Item %%A).CreationTime=$(Get-Date)"`

Comment: That will work as well, but the `$()` isn't neccessary. The pipe doesn't slow down powershell as much as it does in cmd. Starting powershell itself will be the bigger delay.

Comment: @Squashman, I'll accept your test results, I don't have a Windows PC to test this it on ATM. I have however modified my answer by utilising both `Copy` and `Move`, _(it is also untested)_.

Comment: I can approve @Squashman test results (they depend partly on the underlying file system, on my NAS LWT and LAT was changed). Your latest mod changes successfully **ALL** three times.

Comment: Good job everyone.